# React vitejs Unexpected string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, vite, apollo-client

I was installing the @apollo/client library in my vite project and when i called

`new InMemoryCache()` from the apollo library i got console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

And if i clicked on the file where the error comed from (apollo dependency) this wa the red underlined line `((_globalThis$process = globalThis.process) === null || _globalThis$process === void 0 ? void 0 : _globalThis$"development") === "production" ? function instanceOf2(value, constructor) { return value instanceof constructor;`

I tried so many things, using different cache libraries, changing vite condig js but I couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an error introduced with version 16.7.0 of the `graphql` package. Please downgrade for 16.6.0 for now, we are looking into this.

---

Edit: this should be fixed with 16.7.1 now.

Comment: Is there any way you could share your project to help us debug this?

Comment: This seems like it is not a problem with the package itself - do you have any additional bundle config in place?

Comment: I just want to confirm that downgrading graphql to 16.6.0 fixed the issue. I received this error:

`code
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string (at chunk-SALCFXIS.js?v=2629e44a:937:113)
`

After I downgraded, the error went away.

Comment: By now, also 16.7.1 has been released which should fix the problem.

Comment: @phry I am getting this error with `16.8.0`, `16.6.0` works for me

Comment: It appears the error was not fixed in 16.7.1, it is still occurring in 16.8.1.

Comment: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/3918

Answer (score 3):

i got that error also in 16.7.1.

node --version  v18.16.1
npm --version 9.5.1

Only thing that works right now is to downgrade to 16.6.0 like Mark Kurkowski said!